# Swift structs defined in separate files do they need initialisers?

Tags: swift, struct

I have defined a simple struct in a separate swift file as follows:

```
import AppKit

//Declaring a new struct for Company

public struct CompanyStruct {
    var idCompany: Int
    var company: String
    var compType: String
}
```

However, when I try to use this struct it finds the struct if do:

```
var c = CompanyStruct
```

and I can select it but I get no parameters prompted when I open the bracket. If I initialise the struct as:

```
import AppKit

//Declaring a new struct for Company

public struct CompanyStruct {
    var idCompany: Int
    var company: String
    var compType: String


    init(idCompany: Int, company: String, compType: String) {
        self.idCompany = idCompany
        self.company = company
        self.compType = compType
    }
}
```

Then it works fine if I use the struct in say View Controller

I thought you did not have to initialise structs? Is it because I define the struct in an separate file?

Comment: No you don't need to add initialiser for struct. It has member wise initialiser by default. This is an xCode bug. When it happens just use `YourStruct.init` and it will show autocompletion. After that you can remove init part and it will work for the rest structs.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Glad it was a bug in xcode and not my not mis understanding

Comment: I will post my comment as an answer in case somebody bumps into this. Can you accept it?

Answer (score 3):

No you don't need to add initialiser for struct. It has member wise initialiser by default. This is an xCode bug. When it happens just use `YourStruct.init` and it will show autocompletion. After that you can remove init part and it will work for the rest of the structs.

Comment: Thanks! This turned out to be the case for me as well. OP should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Structs have a default initializer hence you can create an object without passing parameters. 
You can create custom initialiers which you have done. 
One thing about structs is you can't create a convenience initializer.

Answer (score -1):

When you use ( ) after structure name when define instance for it you are making initialization automatically.

```
           Let companyStruct = CompanyStruct ( )
```

But you should give some default values in struct like;

```
           struct CompanyStruct {

                  var idCompany: Int = 1

                      }
```